# Zend Studio 9 trial remote settings ok but upload error

Tags: sftp, zend-studio

I imported a drupal installation from an ftp server by right-clicking `new` -> `project...` ->  `PHP project from remote server`. It's an SFTP connection so I chose `SSH`. All the settings seem to be right because the folder actually gets imported into my project, and it's set to *upload on save*. After the folder is downloaded from the server into my project, the ZS console says `Current restricted directory is /`

So when I make changes and save, nothing happens. If I create a new file in my project folder, and I rightclick `upload to server` nothing happens either. Of course I checked the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my log in data were not the user name and password of the root server, but one of the host folders of the server. Once I used root access data, the problem was solved.